# Check if file has a CSV format with Python

Tags: python, csv

Could someone provide an effective way to check if a file has CSV format using Python ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Your question could use more detail.  As a starter, could you please define what you mean by "csv format?"  You'll need to carefully define this format.  Do there exist escape characters, comment markers, or quotation characters in this format?

If this question is homework, please add a tag named "homework" so responses can give you the right kind of guidance.

Comment: I mean on CSV file Comma-separated values file see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values for more details .;

Comment: If by csv 'comma separated values' is meant, then there is no standart of that format.

Comment: @Max There is no official standard format for CSV, you're correct, but I find the csv module in the standard library has really good support for the *de facto* standards.

Comment: @Joe Why not accepting an answer that works?

Answer (score 39):

You could try something like the following, but just because you get a dialect back from [`csv.Sniffer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) really won't be sufficient for guaranteeing you have a valid CSV document.

```
csv_fileh = open(somefile, 'rb')
try:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_fileh.read(1024))
    # Perform various checks on the dialect (e.g., lineseparator,
    # delimiter) to make sure it's sane

    # Don't forget to reset the read position back to the start of
    # the file before reading any entries.
    csv_fileh.seek(0)
except csv.Error:
    # File appears not to be in CSV format; move along
```

Comment: *"...won't be sufficient for guaranteeing..."*: Yeah. Without providing a dialect, mine detected a .ZIP as a valid CSV, with @ as separator

Comment: Why open the file in binary mode? In Python 3, the sample is then refused: "cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". So, the first line should be: csv_fileh = open(somefile, 'rt')

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [the answer by gotgenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985005/1345238):
I reached good results with also checking for non-printable characters that should(tm) not be included in csv files.

```
def is_csv(infile):
    try:
        with open(infile, newline='') as csvfile:
            start = csvfile.read(4096)

            # isprintable does not allow newlines, printable does not allow umlauts...
            if not all([c in string.printable or c.isprintable() for c in start]):
                return False
            dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(start)
            return True
    except csv.Error:
        # Could not get a csv dialect -> probably not a csv.
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), so you could try parsing it under a variety of different dialects.

Answer (score -1):

Try parsing it as CSV and see if you get an error.

Answer (score -2):

You need to think clearly on what you consider a CSV file to be.

For example, what sort of characters can occur between the commas. Is it text-only? Can it be Unicode characters as well? Should every line have the same number of commas?

There is no strict definition of a CSV file that I'm aware of. Usually it's ASCII text separated by commas and every line has the same number of commas and is terminated by your platform's line terminator.

Anyway, once you answer the questions above you'll be a bit farther on your way to knowing how to detect when a file is a CSV file.