# Python to check if a gzipped file is xml or csv

Tags: python, xml, csv, gzip

I have a script to pull in a variety of gzip and bz2 compressed files. After I pull them in, I am looking to write a script to write the file and add an extension based on the file type contained within.

The file formats I am concern about include xml, csv, and txt files, although I am not really concerned about delineating between csv and txt files (adding the txt extension is alright for both).

I have been using the python-magic library to determine which decompression library to use (bz2 vs gzip) but want to know what the easiest way to determine the file type. Using python-magic I got:

```
>>> ftype = m.from_file("xml_test.xml")
>>> ftype
'ASCII text'
>>> ftype = m.from_file("csv_test.csv")
>>> ftype
'ASCII text'
```

My current plan is to read in the first line of each file and make the determination based on that. Is there an easier way?

In response to @phihag's answer showing me how poorly I originally worded this question:
What I want is something that will check first if a file is valid XML, if not then check if it is valid CSV, and finally if it is not valid CSV but is valid plain text, return that as a response

Note: There was a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984888/check-if-file-has-a-csv-format-with-python) but this solution only describes csv check, not an xml, txt, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reliably distinguish XML and csv, as the following file is both a valid XML as well as a valid CSV document:

```
<r>,</r>
```

Therefore, all you can do is apply a heuristic, for example return xml if the first character is `<`, and csv otherwise.

Similarily, all CSV and XML files are also valid plain text files.

To check whether a file forms a valid XML or CSV document, you can simply parse it. If you're out for performance, simply skip the construction of an actual document tree, for example with [sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) or by ignoring the items of [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html):

```
import xml.sax,csv
def getType(filename):
  with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
    try:
      xml.sax.parse(fh, xml.sax.ContentHandler())
      return 'xml'
    except: # SAX' exceptions are not public
      pass
    fh.seek(0)

    try:
      for line in csv.reader(fh):
        pass
      return 'csv'
    except csv.Error:
      pass

    return 'txt'
```

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't thinking about your pretty obvious response giving a valid CSV/XML. My original question was somewhat incomplete, I'll edit my question to better indicate what I'm looking for

Comment: @SamJohnson Updated with a solution that checks whether the input is valid XML, and then whether it's valid CSV.

Comment: the solution for csv vs. text did not seem to work on a few files I tested. Instead I used the solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984888/check-if-file-has-a-csv-format-with-python) which, while not 100% solvent, should take care of almost all cases